# The ReadAsync method cannot be called when another read operation is pending

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I have some PDFs stored in my dropbox location and want users to be able to retrieve them via a call to an API.

```
    [HttpGet("{key}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetPDF(string key) {
        
        string? path = GetPath(key);
        if (path == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }
        using(System.Net.Http.HttpClient wc = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()) {
            try {
                using(System.IO.Stream stream = await wc.GetStreamAsync(path)) {
     //           using(System.IO.Stream stream = wc.GetStreamAsync(path).GetAwaiter().GetResult()) {
                    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
                }                
            } catch(System.Exception ex) {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
    }
```

It runs right through, without hitting the exception, and returns, then gives the error

The ReadAsync method cannot be called when another read operation is pending.

Waiting for the async method didn't help.

Comment: Inject a singleton instance of `HttpClient` (or better yet, use `IHttpClientFactory`) into your controller, instead of newing one up everytime. Also, stick with `await wc.Get..` and don't use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` which is "sync over async".

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary issue appears to be that the stream has been disposed before the function returns. `FileStreamResult` will dispose the stream, you don't need to do that.

Also, `HttpClient` should be a global field, otherwise you could get socket exhaustion issues.

```cs
HttpClient wc = new HttpClient();

[HttpGet("{key}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetPDF(string key)
{
    string? path = GetPath(key);
    if (path == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    
    try
    {
        var stream = await wc.GetStreamAsync(path);
        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
    }
    catch(System.Exception ex)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Note that for dropbox, the last parameter "?dl=0" means that it does NOT return the PDF, but a page displaying the PDF. Use "?dl=1" to actually download the file, which allows me to return it.

Comment: Interesting, I would have expected an `ObjectDisposedException`. In my case this occurred in MAUI Blazor Hybrid, but not in Blazor WASM.

Comment: I think because the dispose is still pending while the read is being tried. If the dispose had completed then you probably would get that exception.