# NotSupportedException: The ReadAsync method cannot be called when another read operation is pending

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, webapi

> NotSupportedException: The ReadAsync method cannot be called when another read operation is pending.

I am trying to download a file using URI but it is giving the above exception.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Downloadfile(string userId, CancellationToken ct)
{
    string docId = $"tinyurl:{userId}";
    DocumentResponse response1 = await blobManager.GetCustomUrlByUserId(docId, ct);
    TinyUrl tinyUrl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TinyUrl>(response1.Content);

    using HttpClient wc = new();
    using Stream stream = await wc.GetStreamAsync(tinyUrl.ActualUrl);
            
   return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/zip");           
}
```

Strangely, this code is working when I put a debugger in my code. I have seen some similar questions here but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Aside from anything else, as the method returns you're disposing of both the stream and the `HttpClient` which is providing it - but that stream is being used by the `FileStreamResult`. That seems like a recipe for problems.

Comment: your solution worked but Not disposing of it can lead to potential memory issues. Correct me if I am wrong. @JonSkeet

Comment: I'd expect FileStreamResult to close the stream itself, and I'd recommend against creating a new HttpClient on each request anyway.

Comment: So I have to declare `HttpClient ` globally. Right @JonSkeet

Comment: No, I'd suggest using dependency injection after reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory. You *can* use a single instance if you're careful - see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Downloadfile(string userId, CancellationToken ct)
{
    string docId = $"tinyurl:{userId}";
    DocumentResponse response1 = await blobManager.GetCustomUrlByUserId(docId, ct);
    TinyUrl tinyUrl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TinyUrl>(response1.Content);

    using HttpClient wc = new();
    Stream stream = await wc.GetStreamAsync(tinyUrl.ActualUrl)；          
    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/zip"); 
}
```

Edit：I just modify the code. from further reading, I find out that we don't need to write "using" for Stream, because FileStreamResult will dispose the stream accordingly.

Refer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73098107/13218799

Comment: I wonder how you will access the `result` outside using block.

Comment: Haha, didn't realize it before, thanks for detecting the bug @JugPatel

Comment: Still getting the same issue.